# Quickest way to set up a HTTP/2 webserver on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, http-2

I'm looking to do some testing with HTTP/2 on Amazon EC2 and am wondering what the quickest way is to set up such a temporary server there.

I was hoping that there would be some ready-to-go AMI images that include HTTP/2 support, but haven't found any yet. I'm preferring either an Apache-based or Nginx-based setup, the flavor of Linux does not matter.

Any thoughts on shortcuts to get a HTTP/2 server running quickly on EC2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most easiest way to setup Apache on an EC2 instance is to configure a script that will download and launch during instance start.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
service httpd start
```

More detailed instruction about how to do it is here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Thank you, but how does that specifically enable HTTP/2?

Comment: Only thing you need to do is to find appropriate command to configure HTTP/2 and specify it in the script. Here is what google gives:
https://icing.github.io/mod_h2/howto.html

Comment: Thank you, will give this a try as soon as I get access to my AWS account.

Comment: this is not an answer: AWS Linux 2 does not include the mod_http2.so file,  which is the http2 module

Answer (score 3):

The new version of Amazon Linux AMI (2017.09) was released. As the part of upgrade now AMI linux uses OpenSSL 1.0.2k and HTTP/2 protocol is now supported by AMI’s httpd24 and nginx. You can upgrade your instance by running these two commands

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update
```

After that you should reboot your instance and change your webserver's configs to run thru HTTP/2 protocol.

Comment: in addition, you'll need to add `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1` to your `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to install and compile from source. Download OpenSSL and NGINX source. After you've compiled OpenSSL, compile NGINX with this flag.

```
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/usr/bin/oopenssl-1.0.2j
```

(or whatever version of SSL you're using.

https://www.elasticbin.com/amazon-linux-nginx-http2-0/